# Equality between two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need some help in the following exercise:

Let $X$, $Y$ be arbitrary sets and let $f : X \to Y$ be an arbitrary function. Prove

(1) $f \left(\bigcup A_i\right)= \bigcup f(A_i)$

(2) $f \left(\bigcap A_i\right) \subseteq \bigcap f(A_i)$

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$, then $f$ is defined on elements of $X$, not on subsets of $X$.  Hence $f(\cup A_i)$ and $f(\cap A_i)$ are meaningless expressions, regardless of what the $A_i$ are (presumably subsets of $X$).

Comment: The common definition is this one: if $A\subset X$, then $f\left(A\right)\equiv\left\{y\in Y \mid y=f\left(x\right) \text{ for some } x\in A\right\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: Old habits die hard; I am using $\subset$ to denote what you
refer to as $\subseteq$.

As I mentioned in the comments, if $A\subset X$,
$$
f\left(A\right)\equiv\left\{ y\in Y\mid y=f\left(x\right)\text{ for some }x\in A\right\} .
$$
(1) To show that two sets are equal (i.e. to show that, for example,
$f\left(\bigcup A_{i}\right)=\bigcup f\left(A_{i}\right)$), you can
show that they one is a subset of the other, and vice versa (i.e.
$f\left(\bigcup A_{i}\right)\subset\bigcup f\left(A_{i}\right)$ and
$\bigcup f\left(A_{i}\right)\subset f\left(\bigcup A_{i}\right)$).
Suppose $y\in f\left(\bigcup A_{i}\right)$. Then, there exists some
$x\in\bigcup A_{i}$ s.t. $f\left(x\right)=y$. Since $x\in\bigcup A_{i}$,
it must be in one of the sets $A_{i}$ for some particular $i$. Therefore,
$y\in f\left(A_{i}\right)$ and hence $y\in\bigcup f\left(A_{i}\right)$.
This proves that $f\left(\bigcup A_{i}\right)\subset\bigcup f\left(A_{i}\right)$.
Now you just need to finish the other direction (i.e. $\bigcup f\left(A_{i}\right)\subset f\left(\bigcup A_{i}\right)$).
Start by assuming $y\in\bigcup f\left(A_{i}\right)$ and continue
as above.

(2) This is essentially the same idea except it's even easier than
(1) because you only need to do one of the ``directions.''

**Answer to your second question**:
Let $y\in f\left(\bigcap A_{i}\right)$. Then there exists some $x\in\bigcap A_{i}$
s.t. $f\left(x\right)=y$. That is, for each $i$, $x\in A_{i}$.
In other words, $y\in f\left(A_{i}\right)$ for each $i$, and hence
$y\in\bigcap f\left(A_{i}\right)$. This proves (2). Suppose now that
$y\in\bigcap f\left(A_{i}\right)$. Then for each $i$, $y\in f\left(A_{i}\right)$.
Then, for each $i$, there exists some $x_{i}\in A_{i}$ s.t. $f\left(x_{i}\right)=y$.
However, it is not necessarily true that $\bigcap A_{i}$ contains
any of these $x_{i}$!

This suggests that when the function $f$ is injective (i.e. for all
$x,x^{\prime}\in X$, $f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)\iff x=x^{\prime}$),
we have equality. So all you need to think of is a function that is
not injective. Take for example $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
$f\left(x\right)=x^{2}$. Consider $A_{1}=\left\{ 1\right\} $ and
$A_{2}=\left\{ -1\right\} $. Then $\bigcap A_{i}=\emptyset$ and
hence $f\left(\bigcap A_{i}\right)=f\left(\left\{ 1\right\} \bigcap\left\{ -1\right\} \right)=f\left(\emptyset\right)=\emptyset$.
However, $\bigcap f\left(A_{i}\right)=f\left(A_{1}\right)\bigcap f\left(A_{2}\right)=\left\{ 1\right\} \bigcap\left\{ 1\right\} =\left\{ 1\right\} \supset\emptyset=f\left(\bigcap A_{i}\right).$

Comment: Thanks for your help, par. I have an additional question: How can I find an example where the inclusion in (2) is strict and how can I "manipulate" f that the inclusion is in fact an equality?

Comment: See my edit. As for "manipulating" $f$, you have to restrict it to be injective. For example, for the case of $f\left(x\right)=x^2$, we can restrict our domain to be the nonnegative subset of $\mathbb{R}$. That way, we "throw out" the negative domain which is, in some sense, repetitive.

Comment: Another remark: Can I prove the following in the same way as problem (1)? $f^{-1} \left(\bigcup A_i\right)= \bigcup f^{-1}(A_i)$

Comment: Yes you can use the same approach in my answer.